# Programmatically remove excel cell edit mode

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

we are working on creating an excel add-in using office-js API's. We have used ***delayForCellEdit*** property when we load data ( which will be called when data is changed in predefiined cell range ). When a user edits a cell and click outside the cell then the cell edit mode is exited but if the user clicks in the Add-in after editing a cell the cell edit mode is not exited. Is there a way to exit cell edit mode programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not support programmatically exit cell edit mode at this moment. I would suggest that you could create a feature request at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563, and upvote your request. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the conformation. It was very help full.